# Best way to check if String is in alphabetical order?

Tags: java

This is the most intuitive way to check if a five character String is in alphabetical order?

```
String newStr = "Hello";

if (newStr.charAt(0) <= newStr.charAt(1) &&
    newStr.charAt(1) <= newStr.charAt(2) &&
    newStr.charAt(2) <= newStr.charAt(3) &&
    newStr.charAt(3) <= newStr.charAt(4)) {
        System.out.println("In order");
} else
    System.out.println("NOT in order");
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a words each preceding letter is smaller than the successive letter in alphabetic order or you want to compare to words basis of alphabetic order

Comment: use a for loop with length

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user3127499 check if a words each preceding letter is smaller

Comment: @trama checkout your anwser below its solves the prob

Comment: @trama check out my answer using regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello";
    char[] newStr = str.toCharArray();
    char previous = '\u0000';
    isInOrder(previous,newStr); 

}

private static boolean isInOrder(char previous, char[] arr) {
    for (char current : arr) {
        if (current < previous)
            return false;
        previous = current;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1! Though I suspect the OP wants a case-insensitive solution but fails to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

In your case this might be good enough.
But think of it as you want to do this to Strings longer than five characters... than it will be a very long if-statement and much more work to do.

I'd rather suggest to use a loop, then you dont need to fix the length of your String.

I.e.

```
boolean sorted = true;
for(int i = 0; i < newStr.length()-1; i++){
    if(newStr.charAt(i) >= newStr.charAt(i+1)){
      sorted = false;
      break;
    }
}
if(sorted){
    System.out.println("In order");
}else{
    System.out.println("NOT in order");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Regular Expression like below :

```
public boolean checkString(String str)  
{
   String str = "^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$";
   Pattern pattern = null;
   Matcher matcher;
   try{
         pattern = Pattern.compile(str,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

         System.out.println(matcher.matches());*/
         matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello");
         return matcher.matches();
      }
   catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
   }  
}
```

Your Main class or from where you call above function :

```
String myStr = "Hello";  
boolean isAlphaOrder = checkString(myStr);  
if(isAlphaOrder)  
  System.out.println("String is in order");
else
   System.out.println("NOT in order");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the most simplest one, then perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello";
    System.out.println(alphabeticalOrder(str.toLowerCase()));

}
public static boolean alphabeticalOrder(String str){
    for(int i = 0;i<str.length()-1;i++)         
        if(str.charAt(i) > str.charAt(i+1))
            return false; 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that for a string of 100 chars, that will call toLowerCase() 200 times, and thus iterate over the 100 chars of the String 200 times, and create 200 String instances?

Comment: @JBNizet Ohh, I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that letter in capital have not the same index that their letter not in capital.

So if you want that abcDe return true, you should also use a tempory String to do you check like this :

```
String yourString ="..."
String tmp = yourString.toLowerCase();
boolean isInOrder = testYourString(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str="Hello";
        str=str.toLowerCase();
        char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ch);
        String str1="";
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            str1+=ch[i]+"";
        }
        if(str1.equals(str))
        {
            System.out.println("In order");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NOT in order");
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the logic needs to be improved

for input String **"AbCd"** & **HeLLo**  code is printing **not in order**

```
You have tried to compare the ascii values of characters and you know that for 
same case letters (lower Case or Upper Case) ascii values would be in increasing order. 
Hence your logic stays intact if input string is in same case : 
e.g. "hello" ,"HELLO", "abcd" or "ABCD"
```

*If you are using string with Mixed Case letters then it wont work correctly.*